# Swift mask UIView constraints issues

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, constraints

I've created a mask view for my camera screen that blurs everything except for a small rectangle in the middle.  I'm having issues when testing on different screen sizes. I'm testing on an 11 Pro and an 8.  If my storyboard view has the proper device selected, the constraints look fine on the device.  But if I switch phones without changing in the storyboard, it is incorrect.  I'm programmatically creating the mask view.  Any help would be much appreciated!

```
func setupBlur() {
    if !UIAccessibility.isReduceTransparencyEnabled {

        blurView.backgroundColor = .clear

        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)

        blurEffectView.frame = blurView.bounds
        blurEffectView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        blurEffectView.addConstraints(blurView.constraints)
        blurView.addSubview(blurEffectView)


        let maskView = UIView(frame: blurView.bounds)
        maskView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        maskView.addConstraints(blurView.constraints)
        maskView.backgroundColor = .clear
        let outerbezierPath = UIBezierPath.init(rect: blurView.bounds)

        let croppedOriginX = (blurView.bounds.width / 2) - (captureView.bounds.width / 2)
        let croppedOriginY = (blurView.bounds.height / 2) - (captureView.bounds.height / 2)
        let frame = CGRect(x: croppedOriginX, y: croppedOriginY, width: captureView.bounds.width, height: captureView.bounds.height)

        let innerRectPath = UIBezierPath.init(rect: frame)
        outerbezierPath.append(innerRectPath)
        outerbezierPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = true

        let fillLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        fillLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
        fillLayer.fillColor = UIColor.green.cgColor // any opaque color would work
        fillLayer.path = outerbezierPath.cgPath
        maskView.layer.addSublayer(fillLayer)

        blurView.mask = maskView;

    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: once you have added the blurView, try calling view.layoutIfNeeded() .

Comment: I assume you;re trying to apply the same constraints to maskView as already exist on blurview by `maskView.addConstraints(blurView.constraints)` ?  I don't think this will work as expected as the constraints are tied to the views/anchors they were created with, not generic anchors that will apply to any view.  Try setting the constraints explicitly.

Comment: What are the constraints that are set on your blurView in your storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.setupBlur()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because when you call `setupBlur()` from `viewDidLoad`, at the beginning `blurView.bounds` values are from `stroyboard` which you're working on it, and you are using these bounds to setup `blurEffectView.frame` before they are adjusted for your device's screen.

This is not the best solution, but I hope it will resolve your problem.

Try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
        self.setupBlur()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! You were correct. Based off your answer, I was able to find a cleaner solution.

`override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.setupBlur()
    }`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've tried `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` instead of `DispatchQue` but it didn't work. However, `viewDidLoad()` worked for me.

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    self.setupBlur()
}
```