# swift UIVisualEffectView with mask autolayout varies by iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, mask, uivisualeffectview

I am working with swift `UIVisualEffectView` with `mask` option.
I am trying to make a blurred `UIVisualEffectView` masked by `UIImageView`.
I've set autolayout constraints to the views at the storyboard but the result varies through the iOS device.
Storyboard, code and results are attached below.
I would be glad if anyone help me.
I've set all auto layout constraints at the storyboard.(Capture included below)
Code is very simple. I've only set `blurView.mask = topImageView`.

```swift
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var bottomImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var topImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var blurView: UIVisualEffectView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        blurView.mask = topImageView
    }

// Still same issue when I move the mask to 'viewDidLayoutSubviews()' method
//
//    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
//        super.viewDidLoad()
//        blurView.mask = topImageView
//    }

}
```

[Storyboard and Code capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBmKY.png)

[Results depending on iOS versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xd4E.jpg)

---
I've tried to move `mask` code from `viewDidLoad()` method to `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` but it's still same.

Comment: I think you mean it varies by device, because all those simulators are running iOS 14.4. The solution is to apply the mask on `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Thank you for the comment. I changed the word 'version' to 'device' like you mentioned. Anyway, I moved the `mask` code from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidLayoutSubview` but it's still same. :(..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-solved by the below code.
Received a hint from similar issue : 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58998541/swift-mask-uiview-constraints-issues/59037761'

```swift
override func viewDidAppear() {
    self.setupBlur()
}
```